# Create an album on a page via facebook app, but only page manager can see that album

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have to post a regular weekly report every week on my fan page wall, so I created an facebook app to do it automatically. The problem is, I can create an album and add some photos successfully, but **only the page administrator can see the album**. I check the album info by facebook tools/explorer, and the album privacy is **everyone**, so I dont know how could it happen! I need your help and thanks for you help.

**Album url**: 
https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.394051570657835.95561.196520877077573&type=3

**Album info on facebook tools explorer:**
http://base.pokey.cc/pokey/picture/fb_info.jpg

**Fan page url:**
www.facebook.com/RightPet.cc

---

**Here is my javascript code to create the album:**

```
var args = {};
args.access_token = 'PAGE_TOKEN',
args.name = 'Album_name...',
args.type = 'album',
args.message = 'Album description...',
FB.api('/'+PAGE_ID+'/albums', 'post', args, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert(response.error.message);
    } else {
        window.open('url.php','_blank');
    }
});
```

---

**Here is my php code to add photos to the album:**

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('access_token' => 'PAGE_TOKEN';
$args['source'] = "@" . "PHOTO_ROOT";
$args['message'] = "Photo message...";
```

Best regards,
Pokey

Comment: Check the settings for your page; especially _“Default visibility of posts by others on {page}'s timeline”_

Comment: @CBroe Hi, I have check that, it is "allow" already